# How to detach from docker container running within another container

Tags: ubuntu, docker

I have a situation where I need to manage docker container(s) (I'll reference these as worker containers) from within one specific container (I'll reference it as manager container). To accomplish this I installed docker on manager container (docker inside docker) and attached to a worker container. Once I am done, I need to detach from the worker container and possibly attach to another worker container or do some other operations on the manager container. Stopping either worker or manager container is not an option.

Pressing `Ctrl-p`, `Ctrl-q` kicks me back to the host and not to the manager container. If I attach back to manager container I can see I'm still connected to the container I was managing. Answers to similar posts suggest `Ctrl-p`, `Ctrl-p`, `Ctrl-q` but that does not work either.

Is there any other way to detach from a container instead of using above mentioned key combination? I am running docker on Ubuntu, manager container is also running on Ubuntu but worker containers can be pretty much anything.

Comment: If you include a transcript of exactly how you are starting the containers, the responses, etc., it would be easier to see what is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a few days of looking for answer I found out the answer so I'm sharing it in case someone else runs into the same issue.

So if you want to run container within container you should **not use**:

```
docker attach container1
docker attach container2
```

Apparently this is not correct way of attaching container to a container. Hence there is no way to detach from the container2 without killing it.

Instead you should use:

```
docker attach container1
docker exec -i -t container2 bash
```

To exit from the container2 type `exit`. You will be kicked back to continer1 and container2 will continue running in the background. Pressing `Ctrl+p`, `Ctrl+q` will kick you back to host with container2 still 'attached' to container1.

Comment: `docker exec` is rather different to `docker attach` - it starts a new process in the same namespaces.
Also there is no `-it` option to `docker attach`.

Comment: @Bryan Yeah, I figured they are completely different. Tnx for pointing out '-it' typo. That is what happens when you do 3 things at the same time :)

Comment: `docker exec -it alice sh` works for me! You're then able to exit container `alice` with the `exit` command and you'll end up in container `bob` without killing either containers.